# TIdMessage - Attachments Show Up in Body as Base64

Tags: html, delphi, smtp, email-attachments, indy

I'm working on sending emails via SMTP using the Indy components (`TIdMessage`). Such an email needs to be HTML, and needs to carry attachments.

Now if I send an email as plain text (`ContentType := 'text/plain'`), and attach a file, the email sends just fine, attachment found and everything.

However, once I change the `ContentType` to `text/html`, I have a very bizarre result. The entire body of the email gets replaced with apparently the underlying email data (in my words), and shows the attachment in the body as Base64 data.

For example, here's just the first few lines of such a resulting email:

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format

--YGuFowdSjNaa=_khosBzZl5L8uGVtfasBX
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

This is the body of a test email.
--YGuFowdSjNaa=_khosBzZl5L8uGVtfasBX
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="TagLogo.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="TagLogo.jpg"

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASwBLAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcU
FhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgo
KCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wAARCADhAG8DASIA
AhEBAxEB/8QAHAAAAgMBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcFBggEAgED/8QAPxAAAQIFAwEEBwYFAwQDAAAA
AQIDAAQFBhEHEiExCBNBdSI3OFFhsrMUMkJxgZEVIzNSgmJyoRaSosEk0eH/xAAWAQEBAQAA
```

Although the original body was only

```
This is the body of a test email.
```

The code is very simple, matching all the examples I can find online...

```
IdMessage.Charset := 'UTF-8';
IdMessage.ContentType := 'text/html'; // <-- text/plain works fine.....
IdMessage.Body := 'This is the body of a test email.';

... (Assigning Other Unrelated Properties) ...

A := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, 'C:\SomeFile.jpg'); // <-- Originally the only LOC here
A.ContentTransfer := 'base64'; // <-- Tried with and without
A.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream'; // <-- Tried with and without
//A.ContentType := 'image/jpeg'; // <-- Tried with and without
A.ContentDisposition := 'inline'; // <-- Tried with and without
```

Why is this resulting in a "garbage" email, and how do I solve it while supporting HTML email body with attachments?

PS - If it makes any difference, the attachments will be images used in-line in the email body in the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Such an email needs to be HTML, and needs to carry attachments

I have blog articles on Indy's website on this very topic, I suggest you read them:

[HTML Messages](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/rlebeau/2005_08_17_A.aspx)

[New HTML Message Builder class](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/rlebeau/20080116.aspx)

> Why is this resulting in a "garbage" email

In a nutshell, because you are not populating the `TIdMessage` correctly.

In your particular example, you are putting the HTML into the `TIdMessage.Body` property, but you are also adding an item to the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` collection.  That combination has some special handling inside of `TIdMessageClient` (which `TIdSMTP` derives from).  In particular, when:

- the `TIdMessage` is to be MIME-encoded,
- and `TIdMessage.IsMsgSinglePartMime` is false,
- and `TIdMessage.IsBodyEmpty()` returns false (when `TIdMessage.Body` contains non-whitespace text),
- and `TIdMessage.ConvertPreamble` is true (which it is by default),
- and the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` collection is not empty, and has no `TIdText` objects in it.

Then `TIdMessageClient.SendBody()` will move the HTML to a new `TIdText` object in the `MessageParts` collection, and generate a MIME-encoded email body with the `TIdMessage.Body` text as the first MIME part.  The assumption is that in this combination, the user has put the message plain-text in the `TIdMessage.Body` by accident, so Indy moves it where it needs to be for further processing, without changing anything else in the email.  However, that means the `TIdMessage.ContentType` property is not adjusted (probably a bug that should be looked into). In your case, you are setting the `ContentType` to `text/html` when it really needs to be a MIME `multipart/...` type instead (depending on the relationship of the attachments to the HTML).

So, you are effectively sending an email like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii; boundary="AduWRpEOzrMvJDhg6Jp8EsEFw5Qr1p=_1v"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 8 Aug 2017 12:58:00 -0700

This is a multi-part message in MIME format

--AduWRpEOzrMvJDhg6Jp8EsEFw5Qr1p=_1v
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

This is the body of a test email.

--AduWRpEOzrMvJDhg6Jp8EsEFw5Qr1p=_1v
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
    name="SomeFile.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;
    filename="SomeFile.jpg"

<base64 data here>

--AduWRpEOzrMvJDhg6Jp8EsEFw5Qr1p=_1v--
```

Which tells the receiver of the email that the *entire* email is HTML when it really is not.  It is actually a mix of multiple MIME types working together. Since you want the image to be inside the HTML, the top-level `Content-Type` header needed to be `multipart/related` instead (I go into more detail in my blog articles explaining why that is).

> how do I solve it while supporting HTML email body with attachments?
>
> If it makes any difference, the attachments will be images used in-line in the email body in the end.

When dealing with `TIdMessage`, it is best to either:

- populate only the `TIdMessage.Body` by itself, and ignore the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` collection.
- put everything in the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` collection, text and all, and ignore the `TIdMessage.Body` property.

In this case, since you need attachments, you need to use the `MessageParts` collection, so you can either:

1. put the HTML in a `TIdText` object within the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` collection yourself (don't let `TIdMessageClient` do it for you), and then set the `TIdMessage.ContentType` to `multipart/related`:

   ```
   IdMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/related; type="text/html"';
   ... (Assigning Other Unrelated Properties) ...

   T := TIdText.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, nil);
   T.ContentType := 'text/html';
   T.Charset := 'utf-8';
   T.Body.Text := '<html><body>This is the body of a test email.<p><img src="cid:myimage"></body></html>';

   A := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, 'C:\SomeFile.jpg');
   A.ContentTransfer := 'base64';
   A.ContentType := 'image/jpeg';
   A.ContentDisposition := 'inline';
   A.ContentID := 'myimage';
   ```

   Or, if you want to provide a plain-text message for non-HTML readers, you need to wrap the HTML and plain-text (in that order) inside of `multipart/alternative` instead, while keeping the HTML and image attachment inside of `multipart/related`:

   ```
   IdMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/alternative';
   ... (Assigning Other Unrelated Properties) ...

   T := TIdText.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, nil);
   T.ContentType := 'multipart/related; type="text/html"';

   T := TIdText.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, nil);
   T.ContentType := 'text/html';
   T.Charset := 'utf-8';
   T.Body.Text := '<html><body>This is the body of a test email.<p><img src="cid:myimage"></body></html>';
   T.ParentPart := 0;

   A := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, 'C:\SomeFile.jpg');
   A.ContentTransfer := 'base64';
   A.ContentType := 'image/jpeg';
   A.ContentDisposition := 'inline';
   A.ContentID := 'myimage';
   A.ParentPart := 0;

   T := TIdText.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, nil);
   T.ContentType := 'text/plain';
   T.Charset := 'utf-8';
   T.Body.Text := 'This is the body of a test email.';
   ```
2. use the `TIdMessageBuilderHtml` class, and let it configure the `TIdMessage` content for you:

   ```
   uses
     ..., IdMessageBuilder;

   MB := TIdMessageBuilderHtml.Create;
   try
     // optional...
     MB.PlainText.Text := 'This is the body of a test email.';
     MB.PlainTextCharSet := 'utf-8';

     MB.Html.Text := '<html><body>This is the body of a test email.<p><img src="cid:myimage"></body></html>';
     MB.HtmlCharSet := 'utf-8';
     MB.HtmlFiles.Add('C:\SomeFile.jpg', 'myimage');

     MB.FillMessage(IdMessage);
   finally
     MB.Free;
   end;

   ... (Assigning Other Unrelated Properties) ...
   ```

Comment: I guess I was just assuming that since each attachment has its own content type, that it would know the difference right off the bat, but that assumption was wrong.

Comment: @JerryDodge: To an extent, it does. But there is a lot that goes on during email generation, and the OP is actually hitting a corner-case with some special handling.  I updated my answer to explain what is happening.

Comment: Can I know how can I generate the TIdMessage in MIME format and save it to a file?

Comment: @Leong `TIdMessage` has a `SaveToFile()` method (there is also a secondary one in `TIdMessageHelper`, too)

Answer (score -3):

The content-type should be [multipart/mixed](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html).

Comment: Just tried, and while the attachment goes fine, the body is not HTML (no different from `text/plain`). That part's very important...

Comment: Actually, for images embedded inside the HTML, the HTML and attachments need to be wrapped inside of `multipart/related; type="text/html"`, and there is additional setup required to actually link the attachment to the HTML.