# I am trying to create an email app using indy components in delphi but I am stuck on figuring out how to send an attachment.

Tags: email, delphi

My form contains a TIdSMTP, TIdMessage, TOpenDialog, SSL Handlers, and other visual components. I also have buttons for sending and attaching the different files.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Host := entered_host_TEdit.Text;
  email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Username := entered_username_TEdit.Text;
  email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Password := entered_password_TEdit.Text;

  message_parts_TIdMessage.Clear();
  message_parts_TIdMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := to_sender_email_TEdit.Text;
  message_parts_TIdMessage.Subject := email_subject_TEdit.Text;
  message_parts_TIdMessage.Body.Text := email_body_message_TMemo.Text;

  email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Connect();
  email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Send(message_parts_TIdMessage);
  email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Disconnect();

end;


procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var t:textfile;
s:string;
selected_file:string;
attatchment_message: TIdMessageBuilderHtml;
begin

selected_file := '';
    try
      attatchment_finder_TOpenDialog.InitialDir := 'C:\Documents';
      attatchment_finder_TOpenDialog.Filter := 'All files (*.*)|*.*';

    if attatchment_finder_TOpenDialog.Execute(Handle) then
      selected_file := attatchment_finder_TOpenDialog.FileName;

      if selected_file <>'' then

        attatchment_message := TIdMessageBuilderHtml.Create;
        attatchment_message.HtmlContentTransfer := 'quoted-printable';

        memo_attachment_box_TMemo.Lines.Add(selected_file);
        attatchment_message.Attachments.Add(selected_file);
        attatchment_message.FillMessage(message_parts_TIdMessage);
      finally
      attatchment_finder_TOpenDialog.Free;
    end;
end;
end.
```

What am I doing wrong when adding my selected file? How can I make it so that I can send any file type?

When I click send on my program it adds the file directory text to my memo box but it doesn't actually attach the file onto my TIdMessage component.

thank you!

Comment: That's not your actual code, because it's full of invalid syntax, a missing `begin` after the if statement,  and a missing finally. Can you post your real code?

Comment: Also, a search here for `TIdMessageBuilder` would have turned up [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45575730/62576), which has a detailed answer by Remy Lebeau that would have answered your question.. Please do an extensive search before posting a new question here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The code you have shown clears the entire `TIdMessage` just before sending it, wiping out any attachments that `Button3Click()` may have added beforehand.

In fact, `Button3Click()` shouldn't be doing anything with the `TIdMessage` directly at all. That responsibility belongs solely in `Button1Click()` when it is populating the `TIdMessage` after clearing it.

Also, you are not using `TIdMessageBuilderHtml` correctly. You should be using its `PlainText` or `HTML` property (depending on what kind of text you are sending) instead of setting the `TIdMessage.Body` directly. Without that, `FillMessage()` doesn't set the `TIdMessage.ContentType` correctly. If you are sending plain text instead of HTML, you should be using `TIdMessageBuilderPlain` instead.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  email_builder: TIdMessageBuilderPlain;
  I: integer;
begin
  email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Host := entered_host_TEdit.Text;
  email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Username := entered_username_TEdit.Text;
  email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Password := entered_password_TEdit.Text;

  message_parts_TIdMessage.Clear;
  message_parts_TIdMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := to_sender_email_TEdit.Text;
  message_parts_TIdMessage.Subject := email_subject_TEdit.Text;

  email_builder := TIdMessageBuilderPlain.Create;
  try
    email_builder.PlainText.Assign(email_body_message_TMemo.Lines);
    email_builder.PlainTextContentTransfer := 'quoted-printable';

    for I := 0 to memo_attachment_box_TMemo.Lines.Count-1 do
      email_builder.Attachments.Add(memo_attachment_box_TMemo.Lines[I]);

    email_builder.FillMessage(message_parts_TIdMessage);
  finally
    email_builder.Free;
  end;

  email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Connect;
  try
    email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Send(message_parts_TIdMessage);
  finally
    email_connecter_TIdSMTP.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  attatchment_finder_TOpenDialog.InitialDir := 'C:\Documents';
  attatchment_finder_TOpenDialog.Filter := 'All files (*.*)|*.*';

  if attatchment_finder_TOpenDialog.Execute(Handle) then
  begin
    memo_attachment_box_TMemo.Lines.Add(attatchment_finder_TOpenDialog.FileName);
    // or, if ofAllowMultiSelect is enabled:
    // memo_attachment_box_TMemo.Lines.AddStrings(attatchment_finder_TOpenDialog.Files);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This was very helpful thank you. What should I do if I want to attach any kind of file? I want to be able to send images, pdf files, text files etc.

Comment: @FranciscoOchoa the code I provided in my answer handles all of that. Simply add the desired file paths to the builder's `Attachments` property. It uses the file extensions to know what type of files they are. But if you need more control, `Attachments.Add()` returns a `TIdMessageBuilderAttachment` that has additional sub-properties, like `ContentType`, `(Wanted)FileName`, etc